# PYTHON - Filtering A Dataframe Under Condition

Tags: python, dataframe, filtering

I have a dataset like below. Second column includes a unique number of the each organizations.
There are some organizations that have the same name (like the last row)

| org_name | org_uniq_nr | founder_rank | founder_name | amount_money |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Zoho | 652 | 46 | n1 | m1 |
| Zoho | 652 | 2389 | n2 | m2 |
| a | 1901 | 1299 | n3 | m3 |
| b | 88 | 776 | n4 | m4 |
| c | 6965 | 991 | n5 | m5 |
| b | 88 | 80 | n6 | m6 |
| Zoho | 779 | 1445 | n7 | m7 |

I want to filter organizations that have the lower founder_rank value. eg: There are 2 rows  that have the same org_uniq_nr (Zoho). But I want only one which has lower founder_rank. So the having higher founder_rank row should be deleted.

| org_name | org_uniq_nr | founder_rank | founder_name | amount_money |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Zoho | 106 | 46 | n1 | m1 |
| a | 1901 | 1299 | n3 | m3 |
| b | 88 | 776 | n4 | m4 |
| c | 6965 | 991 | n5 | m5 |
| Zoho | 779 | 1445 | n7 | m7 |

Comment: Why for Zoho the one that remains is the one having the lower founder_rank (46), but for b, it's the one having the higher founder_rank (776)?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the dataframe by the `founder_rank` then group by the `org_name` and take the first record -

`df.sort_values("founder_rank").groupby("org_uniq_nr").first()`

Comment: This drops duplicate names, but duplicate names are allowed, I think changing it to `.groupby("org_uniq_nr")` would make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just want to keep the lowest founder_rank one. you can try this code to accomplish your work.

```js
import pandas as pd

# Assuming your data is stored in a DataFrame named df
data = {
    'org_name': ['Zoho', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'Zoho'],
    'org_uniq_nr': [106, 1901, 88, 6965, 779],
    'founder_rank': [46, 1299, 776, 991, 1445],
    'founder_name': ['n1', 'n3', 'n4', 'n5', 'n7'],
    'amount_money': ['m1', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm7']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


### give your df/datas in any formula with pd, like read_csv etc, no problem. Ive just used your dummy data###

# Convert founder_rank column to numeric type
df['founder_rank'] = pd.to_numeric(df['founder_rank'])

# Sort DataFrame by 'founder_rank'
df.sort_values(by='founder_rank', inplace=True)

# Keep only one Zoho entry with the lowest founder_rank
df_filtered = df.drop_duplicates(subset='org_name', keep='first')

print(df_filtered)
```

Make sure to give your df instead of the dummy one and you would need to use panadas for the script.

Comment: Did you write this code with chatGPT or a similar tool?

Comment: nope, I've taken parts from my old project, why?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community lack of clarity is really not the issue with this answer, it is very clear. It just doesn't solve the actual question and is very likely LLM-produced (judging by the verbose-waffling-writing-style)